# How do I add unique values into my hashmap

Tags: hashmap, set

I created one Employee Class having couple of instance variable. while initializing the objects I gave same values in my Employee properties. I generated my own hashcode and .equals method from eclipse. For adding those elements in a set works fine. But while adding in a map I get confuse. Need some tips.

class Employee{

```
String name ;
String address;
public Employee(String name, String address) {

    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (address == null) {
        if (other.address != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

public class HashcodeEqualsTesting {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<String, Employee> mymap = new HashMap<>(); 
    Set<Employee> myset = new HashSet<>();

    Employee e1 = new Employee("Depak", "India");
    Employee e2 = new Employee("Depak", "India");

    myset.add(e1);
    myset.add(e2);
    System.out.println(myset.size()); // shows 1
    mymap.put("ABC", e1);
    mymap.put("XYZ", e2);
    System.out.println(mymap.size()); // why shows 2

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

To clarify your doubt , according to your implementation both Employee objects i.e. e1 and e2 are equal , so they will be added to set only once.

However , in HashMap, you are adding **two separate Keys** - ABC and XYZ, so hash code of keys will be calculated. (Not of Employee Class), that's why size of your hashMap is 2.

You can refer to following link for deeper understanding of HashMap's internal working -https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/

Answer (score 0):

That is because hashmap allows you to store duplicate values.

You are trying to map "ABC" to e1 and "XYZ" to e2. Even though e1 equals e2, "ABC" is different from "XYZ" and that is why your map's size is two (Now your map has ABC->e1, XYZ->e2).

If you want to prevent adding duplicate values to hashmap, you need to iterate through the entire hashmap before inserting anything into your hashmap and check if the same value is not present.

```
mymap = insertIntoHashMap("ABC",e1,mymap);


public Hashmap<String,Employee> insertIntoHashMap(String key, Employee employee,Hashmap<String,Employee> mymap)
{
    boolean insert = true;
    for(String employeeKey : mymap.keySet())
    {
        if(mymap.get(employeeKey).equals(employee))
        {
            insert = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(insert)
    {
        mymap.put(key,employee);
    }
    return mymap;
}
```